# Converting UnsafeMutablePointer to an Array gives wrong value

Tags: c, swift, bridging-header, unsafemutablepointer

I'm using Swift and should I use C source with Bridging-Header.

C source has like this function.

```
char* testFunc2(char *input) { // input = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    char v1[17] = { 0, };

    memcpy(v1, input, 4);

    return (char*)v1; 
}
```

The v1's value will be [4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0...]

And I input data like this

```
var i1: [Int8] = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let idPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.allocate(capacity: 7)
idPtr.initialize(from: &i1, count: 6)

let tf2 = testFunc2(idPtr)
```

The address value is equal (char*)v1 with tf2.

But when I converted tf2(UnsafeMutablePointer) to Array,

the value is different.

I converted like this

```
let tt2Buf = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: tt2, count: 17)
let tt2Arr = Array(tt2Buf)
```

When I return input(parameter) directly, converted value is right.

But when I did somegthing in C source and returned value,

the converted value is not correct with return value in C source.

I wasted day about 10 days with this problem....

How can I Do.....?

Comment: Did you enable all compiler warnings? You should see something like “Address of stack memory associated with local variable 'v1' returned” ...

Comment: @MartinR It was associated with memory. I didn't learned 'C' so I didn't know the memory which set on local function will be free when returned if it didn't declared dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char v1[17]` is local array, its scope is limited to `testFunc2` function. 
You cannot use its reference outside the function.

Maybe you can allocate memory dynamically and pass its reference.

```
char* testFunc2(char *input) { // input = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    char *v1 = malloc(17);

    memset(v1, 0, 17);
    memcpy(v1, input, 4);

    return v1; 
}
```

However you have to free the memory at some point otherwise you will have memory leaks.

Comment: You are right. Malloc is key of solving the problem. I didn't learned 'C' so I didn't know the memory which set on local function will be free when returned if it didn't declared dynamic. Thank you!